# Surjective function at a subset of its codomain

Tags: functions

In Wikipedia we read:

> In mathematics, a function $f$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ is surjective (or onto), or a surjection, if for every element $y$ in the codomain $Y$ of $f$ there is at least one element $x$ in the domain $X$ of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Can a function $f:A\to B$ be called surjective at a specific subset of its codomain?

I ask if this definition exists:

> A function $f$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ is surjective at a subset $A$ of its codomain if for every element $y$ in the set $A$ there is at least one element $x$ in the domain $X$ of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$.

For example the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
such that $f(x)=x^2$ is not surjective (at its codomain $\mathbb{R}$).
But is it called surjective at $\mathbb{R}_+$ for example?(or each subset of $\mathbb{R}_+$)

By that definition every function is surjective at all subsets of its image.

Comment: "By that definition every function is surjective at all subsets of its image." Not quite: only at its image. It's not a well-defined function for any smaller subset.

Comment: We just say that $A$ is a subset of the image of $f$. I never heard about this definition.

Comment: No, absolutely unusual: A function is surjective at its  image or a subset of it.